# rookie MySql question about paging; Is one query enough?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pagination

I have managed to get paging to work, almost.
I want to display to the user, total nr of records found, and the currently displayed records. Ex:

```
4000 found, displaying 0-100.
```

I am testing this with the nr 2 (because I don't have that many records, have like 20).
So I am using `LIMIT $start, $nr_results;`

Do I have to make two queries in order to display the results the way I want, one query fetching all records and then make a `mysql_num_rows` to get all records, then the one with the LIMIT ?

I have this:

```
 mysql_num_rows($qry_result);
 $total_pages = ceil($num_total / $res_per_page); //$res_per_page==2 and $num_total = 2
    if ($p - 10 < 1) {
       $pagemin=1;
    }
```

else { 
           $pagemin = $p - 10; 
        }
 if ($p + 10 > $total_pages) {
           $pagemax = $total_pages;
        }
 else { 
           $pagemax = $p + 10; 
        }

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  mt.*, 
  fordon.*, 
  boende.*, 
  elektronik.*, 
  business.*, 
  hem_inredning.*, 
  hobby.* 
FROM classified mt 
 LEFT JOIN fordon ON fordon.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
 LEFT JOIN boende ON boende.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
 LEFT JOIN elektronik ON elektronik.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
 LEFT JOIN business ON business.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
 LEFT JOIN hem_inredning ON hem_inredning.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
 LEFT JOIN hobby ON hobby.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
 ORDER BY modify_date DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 2
```

Thanks, if you need more input let me know.

Basically Q is, do I have to make two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, to get the total number of records found, you need another query.
Though your current method of getting total is unacceptable.
You can use either `select count(*) ...` query or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS/FOUND_ROWS()`
 feature

Comment: How should I use the COUNT then? COUNT(mt.*, fordon.* etc) FROM?

Answer (score 1):

You can make do with the following two queries:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM    t_source
LIMIT   100, 10;

SELECT  FOUND_ROWS();
```

The *first* one will return the results, the *second* one will show the number of records that *would* be returned be there no `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query would be a query selecting COUNT(*). [This article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) suggests it may even be faster when appropriate indexes are available:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE ...
```